# Values not populating on the record

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have a lightning component that I'm calling on a quick action. It has a lookup field "Contact" which is prepopulated on the form. When I save the record, the contact value is not reflecting on the newly created record, but if I change the prepopulated contact field to reflect a new value, it works fine. Below is the code. 
What could be the issue?

Lightning component:

```
   <lightning:recordEditForm  objectApiName="RFQ__c" onload="{!c.handleOnload}" recordId="{!v.recordId}"> 

        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
            <div >
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="Desc" fieldName="Description__c" value ="{!v.RFQObj.Description__c}" required="true"  />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                <div >
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id= "contact1" fieldName="Contact__c" value ="{!v.RFQObj.Contact__c}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <lightning:select aura:id="typeA" value ="{!v.RFQObj.Type__c}" name="select1" label="Type" required="true" >
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.typeP}" var="item">
                        <option value="{!item}" >{!item}</option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                <span style="color: #C23930;font-size: .75rem;">{!v.ErrorMessage}</span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="ReceivedDate" fieldName="RFQ_Received__c" value ="{!v.RFQObj.RFQ_Received__c}" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Please select a valid date"/>
                <span style="color: #C23930;font-size: .75rem;">{!v.ErrorMessage1}</span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="RequestedDate" fieldName="Requested_By__c" value ="{!v.RFQObj.Requested_By__c}" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Please select a valid date"/>
                <span style="color: #C23930;font-size: .75rem;">{!v.ErrorMessage2}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="AssignedTo" fieldName="Assigned_To__c" value ="{!v.RFQObj.Assigned_To__c}" required="true" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <lightning:select aura:id="type1" value ="{!v.RFQObj.Product_Groups__c}" name="select1" label="Product Group" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Please select Product Group">
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.productgroup}" var="item">
                        <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                <span style="color: #C23930;font-size: .75rem;">{!v.ErrorMessage3}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

When i use component.find("contact1").get("v.value") in doinit() or any other javascript function, i get the value as undefined.

What could be a way out?

JS Controller:

```
handleOnload: function(component, event, helper){
         component.find("ReceivedDate").set("v.value",null);
         component.find("RequestedDate").set("v.value",null);
         component.find("Desc").set("v.value","");
        var a= component.find("contact1").get("v.value");
         alert("alert" +a);

},
 //creates RFQ record
    onSelect : function(component, event, helper) {
        var isValid = true;
        var isRFQ = component.get("v.recType");
        //var abc = component.find("contact").get("v.value"); 
        //alert('hello '+abc);

        //validation for RFQ record type
        if(isRFQ){
        var recDate = component.find("ReceivedDate").get("v.value"); 
        if($A.util.isEmpty(recDate))
        {               
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage1",'Please enter Received date');
            isValid = false;

        } 



        var reqDate = component.find("RequestedDate").get("v.value");
        if($A.util.isEmpty(reqDate))
        {              
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage2",'Please enter requested date');
            isValid = false;

        } 

        var prodGroup = component.find("type1").get("v.value");
        if($A.util.isEmpty(prodGroup))
        {              
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage3",'Please select Product group');
            isValid = false;
        } 

             var typeS = component.find("typeA").get("v.value");
            alert('typeS'+typeS)
        if($A.util.isEmpty(typeS))
        {              
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage",'Please select type');
            isValid = false;
        } 

        }
        //RFQ record type over

        //Validation for P3 record type start
        if(!isRFQ)
        {
         var recDate = component.find("ReceivedDate1").get("v.value"); 
        if($A.util.isEmpty(recDate))
        {               
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage1",'Please enter Received date');
            isValid = false;
        } 


        var reqDate = component.find("RequestedDate1").get("v.value");
        if($A.util.isEmpty(reqDate))
        {              
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage2",'Please enter requested date');
            isValid = false;
        } 

        var SchDate = component.find("CompletionDate").get("v.value");
        if($A.util.isEmpty(SchDate))
        {              
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage3",'Please enter Scheduled completion date');
            isValid = false;
        } 

        var typeP = component.find("typeQ").get("v.value");
        if($A.util.isEmpty(typeP))
        {              
            component.set("v.ErrorMessage",'Please select Type');
            isValid = false;
        } 

        }

        if(isValid){ 

            component.set("v.errorMessage","");
            component.set("v.errorMessage1","");
            component.set("v.errorMessage2","");
            component.set("v.errorMessage3","");

            var action = component.get("c.createRFQ");              
            action.setParams({          
                RFQObj: component.get("v.RFQObj"),           
                recordId : component.get("v.recordId")                  
            });  
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {


                    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        mode: 'dismissible',
                        message:'Revision Created',
                        type : 'success',
                        duration : 50000
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire();                       
                    location.reload();

                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your controller as well?

Comment: updated in the question @sanketkumar